# Компьтер mac черный экран

Tags: macos

macOs Catalina
Закрыл ноутбук, открыл через какое-то время. Черный экран, выяснил методом тыка что это VoiceOver с включенной шторкой, которая выключила экран. VO-Shift-Fn-_ не работает. При этом я не знаю, какая клавиша у меня для VO, вообще им никогда не пользовался и не знал, что такое существует. Попробовал все клавиши. На все возможные сочетания клавиш, которые могли бы  перезагрузить ноут, он никак не реагирует. Единственный способ перезагрузить ноут - дать ему разрядиться. Единственное что я могу сделать это command+f5, что включает/выключает voiceover. После перезагрузки на секунду вижу экран, (там теперь кста смена пароля потому что я миллион раз ввел его неправильно, когда не понимал что вообще происходит) после чего снова экран потухает. Пробовал запустить в режили эпл диагностики, тоже вижу экран диагностики на секунду и опять все потухает. А ещё у меня ноутбук на английском и на слух я не понимаю, что он мне говорит
Такие дела, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что адресовать его надо в соответствующую техподдержку.

Comment: Соответствующая техподдержка отдыхает из-за коронавируса.

Comment: остаётся спортлото.